# Using keras to load model and assign new values to its parameters

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use keras to store a model and then load it to retrain. My question is how do I set the learning rate to a new value when loading a model?
Here are my code:

```
# Save a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='uniform', input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
# learning rate is 0.001
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit_generator(...)
model.save()
```

Then load the model,

```
model = load_model(model)
# Change the model's parameters here. Set the learning rate to 0.01.
model.fit_generator(...)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I find the answer:

```
from keras import backend as K
# To get learning rate
print(K.get_value(model.optimizer.lr))
# To set learning rate
K.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, 0.001)
keras.__version__ # 2.0.2
```