# Changing optimizer or lr after loading model yields strange results

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm using the latest Keras with Tensorflow backend (Python 3.6)

I'm loading a model that had a training accuracy at around 86% when I last trained it.

The orginal optimizer that I used was :

```
r_optimizer = optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay = .02)
model.compile(optimizer= r_optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

If I load the model and continue training without recompiling, my
accuracy would stay around 86% (even after 10 or so more epochs).
So I wanted to try changing the learning rate or optimizer.

If I recompile the model and try to change the learning rate or the
optimizer as  follows:

```
new_optimizer = optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, decay = .02)
```

or to this one:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr= .0001)
```

and then compile:

```
model.compile(optimizer= new_optimizer ,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit ....
```

The accuracy would reset to around 15% - 20%, instead of starting around 86%,
and my loss would be much higher. 
Even if I used a small learning rate, and recompiled, I would still start
off from a very low accuracy.
From browsing the internet it seems some optimizers like ADAM or RMSPROP have
a problem with resetting weights after recompiling (can't find the link at the moment)

So I did some digging and tried to reset my optimizer without recompiling as follows:

```
    model = load_model(load_path)
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1.0) # very high for testing
    model.optimizer = sgd   #change optimizer

    #fit for training

     history =model.fit_generator(
     train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch = r_steps_per_epoch,
    epochs = r_epochs,
    validation_data=valid_gen,
    validation_steps= np.ceil(len(valid_gen.filenames)/r_batch_size),
    callbacks = callbacks,
    shuffle= True,
    verbose = 1)
```

However, these changes don't seem to be reflected in my training.
Despite raising the `lr` significantly, I'm still floundering around 86% with the same loss. During each epoch, I'm seeing very little loss or accuracy movement. I would expect the loss to be a lot more volatile. 
This leads me to believe that my change in optimizer and lr isn't being
realized by the model.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your change does not assign new lr to optimizer, and I find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523841/using-keras-to-load-model-and-assign-new-values-to-its-parameters) to reset lr values after loading model in Keras, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer referring to what you wrote here:

> From browsing the internet it seems some optimizers like ADAM or RMSPROP have a problem with resetting weights after recompiling (can't find the link at the moment)

Adaptive optimizers such as ADAM RMSPROP, ADAGRAD, ADADELTA, and any variation on these, rely on previous update steps to improve the direction and magnitude of any current adjustment to the weights of the model.

Because of this, the first few steps that they take tend to be relatively "bad" as they "calibrate themselves" with information from previous steps.

When used on a random initialization, this is not a problem, but when used on a pretrained model, these few first steps, can degrade the model so much, that almost all of the pretrained work gets lost.

Even worse, now the training doesn't start from a carefully chosen random initialization like a Xavier initialization, but from some sub-optimal starting point, which could potentially prevent the model from converging to the local optimum that it would have reached if it started from a good random initialization.

**Unfortunately I'm not sure how you can avoid this... Perhaps pretrain with one optimizer --> save weights --> replace optimizer --> restore weights --> train for a few epochs and hope the new adaptive optimizer learns a "useful history" --> than restore the weights agin from the saved weights of the pretrained model and without recompiling start training again, now with a better optimizer "history".**

Please let us know if this works.